# Apply search on Multidimensional array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I search through multiple arrays. I am making custom search functionality for datatable. How can I do that?
I am stuck how can I search and find amongst array and return the array.

```
$records = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28
            [1] => http://198.58.98.34:4600/uploads/item/priority_images-1519195620005Item1.png
            [2] => Currency
            [3] => Demo1
            [4] => Hello
            [5] => 980
            [6] => 2018-02-21T06:47:15.264Z
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 27
            [1] => http://198.58.98.34:4600/uploads/item/1519120091372-filewinter_is_here_game_of_thrones_hd-1920x1080.jpg
            [2] => coins212
            [3] => Demo2
            [4] => Hello1
            [5] => 54564
            [6] => 2018-02-21T06:38:04.053Z
        )
);

$search = $request['search']['value'];
```

I tried using `array_column` but it was not working.
How Can I search and return the searched data.?

Comment: what you want is not clear. Please add expected array  ?, Do you want like where clause in query ?

Comment: It's like,search the particular keyword among the whole array and if matches return those array

Comment: Why you removed laravel tag ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collect` function in laravel to make [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-where) and the use where function to filter

```
$collect =  collect($records);
$search = $collect->where('search_column','value');
```

In your example you can use column number as. ie 3rd column which key is `2`

```
$search = $collect->where('2','Currency');
```

Will give the array which have `Currency` in third columnd ie. with key `2`

Please check all available method for collection [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods)

Comment: Bt u see I have numeric key so what should I do in search_column?

Comment: try with numbers in place of `search_column`. But I suggest to put `keys` instead number.

Comment: Given the example as you want for currency  `$search = $collect->where('2','Currency');`

Comment: share what you tried exactly it is working in my end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method, which will search and return a dot-notatin path :

```
function searchArray($array, $value, $path = '') {
    $collection = collect($array);

    $key = $collection->search($value);

    if ($key !== null) {
        // Value was found in the collection
        return $path . '.' . $key;
    } else {
        // Value was not found in the collection, search nested arrays
        $result = $collection->map(function ($item, $key) use ($value, $path) {
            if (is_array($item)) {
                return searchArray($item, $value, $path . '.' . $key);
            }
        })->filter()->first();

        return $result ?: false;
    }
}

$path = searchArray($object, 'gif-bg');

if ($path !== false) {
    // "gif-bg" was found in the object
    echo "Path: " . $path;
} else {
    // "gif-bg" was not found in the object
}
```

If you just want to search you can use collect as following

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

$results = collect($records)->where(function ($record) use ($search) {
    foreach ($record as $value) {
        if (strpos($value, $search) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
});

return $results;
```

If you want to search a specific column in the array, you can modify the inner for each loop to only check the values in that column.

```
    $results = [];
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        if (strpos($record[2], $search) !== false) {
            $results[] = $record;
        }
    }

return $results;
```

This will only check the values in the third column for the search term, and add the record to the results array if a match is found.